# Loading GML data into Postgres - No geom!

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ogr2ogr, gml

I'm trying to load an Environment Agency GML file into Postgres/PostGIS using ogr2ogr. The file loads fine, all the other data is there, but when I check the table in the database there is no geometry column. As it is a polygon dataset this is a problem!

ogr2ogr command is:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=* port=* dbname=* user=* password=*" RoFRS_v201701.gml -overwrite -progress --config PG_USE_COPY YES
```

The GML file has a XSD file with it.

Also the GML opens perfectly in QGIS, with polygons displayed as they should be.

Any suggestions for getting the geom into Postgres?

**Update:**

Results from ogrinfo:

```
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 2130752
Extent: (134111.801000, 11510.471300) - (655988.124900, 657600.687500)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
OBJECTID: Integer (0.0)
PROB_4BAND: String (8.0)
SUITABILITY: String (25.0)
PUB_DATE: Integer (0.0)
RISK_FOR_INSURANCE_SOP: String (3.0)
SHAPE_Length: Real (0.0)
SHAPE_Area: Real (0.0)
```

Comment: What `ogrinfo RoFRS_v201701.gml -al -so` shows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution as it turns out, but I will post it here in case anyone comes across the same problem in future:

I renamed the .XSD file so it was ignored, loaded the .GML in QGIS so that a new .GFS file was created, and then ran the ogr2ogr command again to load the data. With the new .GFS file the data load worked fine, complete with a geom column.

Answer (score 2):

> The core **postgis extension** installs **PostGIS** geometry, geography, raster, spatial_ref_sys and all the functions and comments with a simple: **CREATE EXTENSION postgis;** command. [...] (Source: http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html)

It seems like your database is not a PostGIS one (only PostgreSQL), so geometries are not read. Before loading your data, simply execute:

```
ogrinfo PG:"host=* port=* dbname=* user=* password=*" -sql "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
```

**Update:**

PostGIS is enabled yet, so this is not the reason why the gml is not load.

`ogrinfo` doesn't recognize the Geometry Column (no geometryProperty is available), so the associated xsd file could not be valid for OGR. Setting the `GML_ATTRIBUTES_TO_OGR_FIELDS` open option to `YES` would do the job:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=* port=* dbname=* user=* password=*" RoFRS_v201701.gml -overwrite -progress -oo GML_ATTRIBUTES_TO_OGR_FIELDS=YES
```

Comment: Sorry afalciano, I should have specified. This is a postgis enabled database. I have other tables already with geometry.

Comment: @Matt Ok, I can read what `ogrinfo` shows now: the Geometry Column is not reported. That's why is not loaded correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This may, or may not be, an answer to this question, but I seem to remember something exactly similar when I was having help setting up a PostGIS database, and loading Natural England data into it.

So this is the caveat. I haven't written this script, or claim to fully understand it at the moment, but it sorted out some geometry problems that I had, and remains as part of one of the core scripts in the repository. I run it in pgAdmin.

I have permission to share this script here.

I have left the comments in to help

```
- Ensures the geom column contains geometry of plain, 
      ST_MultiPolygon and not the variant with additional dimensions

 -- Run the queries below to check the type of geometry currently stored 
-- in the geom column
-- SELECT DISTINCT ST_GeometryType(geom) FROM schema.table; -- We want ST_MultiPolygon
-- SELECT DISTINCT ST_NDims(geom) FROM schema.table; -- We want 2

-- If the above reports > 2 dimensions, you can force it to 2d by:
-- Adding an additional column called geom_2d of the correct type and projection
ALTER TABLE schema.table
ADD COLUMN geom_2d geometry(MultiPolygon,27700);
-- UPDATing that new column by passing the original geometry through the ST_Force2D
-- PostGIS function
UPDATE schema.table SET geom_2d = ST_Force2D(geom);
-- Dropping the original geometry
ALTER TABLE schema.table DROP COLUMN geom;
-- Renaming the new column to geom
ALTER TABLE schema.table RENAME COLUMN geom_2d TO geom;
-- Clean up any duplicate vertices and other geometry problems
DELETE FROM schema.table WHERE ST_Area(geom) = 0.0;
UPDATE schema.table 
SET geom = ST_Multi(ST_Buffer(geom, 0.0)) 
WHERE NOT ST_IsValid(geom);

-- And adding a spatial index to the new column
CREATE INDEX sidx_table_geom
  ON schema.table
 USING gist
(geom);
```